# OnClickListener for Menu Items in Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, menu-items

**What I am using?** 
I am writing the default navigation drawer activity by using kotlin

**My Question**
There is a "three dot dropdown menu" as per image:

[image]

Few functions being invoked when i click the menu's. Not sure which piece of code being executed.
**My Problem**
There are many tutorials out there for Navigation Drawers but I couldn't find anything for the particular case, especially for kotlin.

**drawer.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

**Drawer.kt**
I do not see any code according to menu action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3-dots menu is the [**overflow menu**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#options-menu) and is **not** related to the `DrawerLayout`.

In your `Activity`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val toolbar : Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    ...
}
```

Then you have to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to inflate your previously defined menu resource:

```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
        return
```

Finally override the `onOptionsItemSelected` to handle the click on the item menu:

```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_logout -> //....) return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: the first the pieces of code are done because of the template. but the last piece of code worked just fine. <3

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to handle menu clicks. I am not sure if this has to do anything with `NavigationDrawer`. It does not seems to from the screenshot attached.
If so you should implement [`onOptionsItemSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem))  to handle whatever action you want to happen, eg:

```kotlin
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> println("handle me!") return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

you need to return either `true` or `false` to indicate if menu click was handled by your code (or not).

Comment: ah, might be, I was typing the code by hand. You might need to reformat it and add `{}` around print and return stamtents

Answer (score 0):

You can override this in your MainActivity, To handle the Menu Item clicks

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (menuItem.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings-> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //handle click on settings
        }
        R.id.action_logout-> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //handle click on logout
        }
        
    }
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START) //Closing the drawer
    return true // because you handled the clicks
}
```